# Create hyperlink with js dom

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a wikipedia viewer, get json data and then show it with a hyperlink that take you to the article. The problem is when I want to give the href attribute to a specific element.

```
$.getJSON(url1 + search + url2, function(data) {
  for(i=0; i<data[1].length; i++) {
    var p = document.createElement("P");
    var id = p.setAttribute("id", i);
    var t = document.createTextNode(data[1][i] + ': ');     
    var text = document.createTextNode(data[2][i]);
    var a = document.getElementById(i);
    var link = a.setAttribute("href", data[3][i]);
    p.appendChild(t);
    p.appendChild(text);
    p.appendChild(link);
    document.body.appendChild(p);
  }
});
```

So, I'm calling the specific "p" element by Id(i value) and then I append to it the specific url. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually doesn't make much sense trying to correct parts of your code. The following is a cleaned up and corrected version of yours. Although it is untested, it should produce a format like `<p>data[1][i]: <a href="data[3][i]">data[2][i]</a></p>`.

```
$.getJSON(url1 + search + url2, function(data)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < data[1].length; ++i)
    {
        //main element
        var p = document.createElement("p");
        p.id = "element" + i;    //you should not use just numbers as IDs

        //preceding description
        var t = document.createTextNode(data[1][i] + ': ');

        //actual link
        var text = document.createTextNode(data[2][i]);
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = data[3][i];
        a.appendChild(text);

        //merge all of them together
        p.appendChild(t);
        p.appendChild(a);
        document.body.appendChild(p);
    }
});
```

Comment: ya but also if `p.setAttribute("id", i);`, then `var a = document.getElementById(i);`, it follows that a === undefined, since p is not yet inserted into the DOM.

Answer (score -1):

You are using

```
    p.appendChild(link);
```

You should be using:

```
    p.appendChild(link);
```

I think that's not the only thing wrong, your `var a = document.getElementById(i);` assumes you have an element in the DOM with ids looking like "1" 'var a = document.createElement(a);

```
$.getJSON(url1 + search + url2, function(data){
  for(i=0; i<data[1].length; i++){
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    var t = document.createTextNode(data[1][i] + ': ');             
    var text = document.createTextNode(data[2][i]);
    var a = document.getElementById(i);
    var link = a.setAttribute("href", data[3][i]);
    a.appendChild(t);//put text inside the clickable link
    a.appendChild(text);//put additional text inside the clickable link
    p.appendChild(a);//put the link inside the <p> element
    document.body.appendChild(p);//add the link into the DOM at the end of the body
    });

    //now your element is a <p><a href="someUrl">data[1][i]: data[2][i]</a></p>
```